# characteristic polynomial of an element of a finite flat $R$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

A book I'm reading says this:

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, and $B$ a finite locally free $R$-algebra. Since $B$ is locally free, for every $b\in B$, multiplication by $b$ gives an $R$-linear endomorphism of $B$ as a locally free $R$-module, and consider its characteristic polynomial

$$P_b(T) := \text{det}(T-b)\in R[T]$$

Ie, we cover Spec $R$ with open neighborhoods $U_i$ where $B$ is free, and on each $U_i$ we pick a basis, compute the characteristic polynomial there, and using basis-invariance of the char poly, we glue them together to obtain the char poly "$P_b(T) := \text{det}(T-b)$" in $R[T]$.

Is there a good reference/book that discusses the properties of this characteristic polynomial? (I'm of course familiar with the situation where $R$ is a field. I'm just wondering what carries over from the field case to our case here).

For example, are the roots of $P_b(T)$ precisely the values of $R$ for which there exists a nonzero $x\in B$ with $bx = rx$? Is $P_b(b) = 0$?

Intuitively in terms of algebraic geometry, what does this characteristic polynomial represent/tell you?

Comment: I guess this is related to spectral curves?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250209/what-does-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-an-element-in-a-finite-flat-r-algeb

Comment: Well, a closely related concept is what the trace pairing $(b_1,b_2)=\text{Tr}(b_1b_2)$ (defined in the same way) tell you. In this case, the non-degeneracy is equivalent to $B/R$ being etale. Does that do anything for you?

Comment: This book is Katz & Mazur's one, right ?

Comment: @Suzet Yes that's right.